# creating a numeric vector in r

Tags: r, numeric

I imported a `70104 x 1` matrix with hourly wind speeds into r. I am trying to fit various energy distributions to the data. however, when I try to fir the models, this error comes up "data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1". How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: It would help to see some code. In particular, the function you are using to fit models.

Answer (score 2):

We can just wrap with `c` to convert it to a `vector`

```
v1 <- c(mat)
```

Or explicitly use `as.vector` to strip off the `dim` attributes

```
as.vector(mat)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(70104))
```